# Error: ')' expected

Tags: android

This is a java class of an activity and what im trying to do is generate a toast when a button is clicked but I get the above error. I tried adding a closed parentheses but it threw the same error.

```
public class btntoast extends Fragment
{
Button btn_order;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_in_room_dining, container, false);
    btn_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Updated code to :

```
public class in_room_dining extends Fragment
{
Button btn_order;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    btn_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
 public void onClick(View v)
{
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_in_room_dining, container, false);
}
}
```

The error thrown is :

```
11-29 09:38:22.098    1138-1138/com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ab9ba8)
11-29 09:38:22.138    1138-1138/com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax, PID: 1138
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax.in_room_dining.onCreateView(in_room_dining.java:23)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
```

NOTE: (in_room_dining.java:23) is btn_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Comment: Try code provided by me, hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

You missed ")" for `setOnClickListener`

```
btn_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_in_room_dining, container, false);
```

also its unreachable code because of return statement
put it at the end of `onCreateView`;

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_in_room_dining, container, false);
        btn_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
     public void onClick(View v)
    {
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   });
 }
}

Comment: Error: unreachable statement, missing return statement

Comment: put your return at the end of statement , it prevent setOnclickListener on the next line to run. so its unreachable.

Comment: I updated my code as you said but got new errors in logcat. I will update the question so you can have a look

Comment: @shrbisht : i cant help you more with your error , its NullPointerException so you have to trace your code line by line to find out which value is null.

Comment: your button is null use as i suggested u, btn_order =(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.text);

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
btn_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as simple add `);` after define OnClickListener, like this:

```
    btn_order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: when i edit it to :btn_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()); >>>>> I get >> cannot resolve symbol v for line public void onClick(View v)

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
   public class btntoast extends Fragment
    {
       Button btn_order;
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
          View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
          btn_order =(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
          btn_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
          {
             public void onClick(View v) 
             {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
          });

          return v;
      }
   }
```